# Possibly wrong question in S L Loney Coordinate Geometry

Tags: analytic-geometry

Given question:

> $P, Q, R$ are three points on a parabola and the chord $PQ$ cuts the diameter through $R$ in $V$. Ordinates $PM$ and $QN$ are drawn to this diameter. Prove that $RM.RN = RV^2$

What I did:
I represented the three as parametric points with parameters $t_1, t_2, t_3$ on parabola $y^2 = 4ax$. I found the equation of the chord and then its intersection V with the diameter through R. I then dropped perpendiculars from P and Q to the diameters and took their feet as M and N. But then this is the outcome
$$RM = a(t_1^2-t_3^2)$$
$$RN = a(t_2^2-t_3^2)$$
$$RV = -a(t_1-t_3)(t_2-t_3)$$

Which doesn't seem matching with what's been asked to prove. Where am I going wrong or is the question itself wrong?

Comment: Can you draw a clear picture of the given problem on paper and post a snapshot although I know it yields to downvoting and some frowning people commenting you not to do so.. This sometimes helps us solve.

Comment: "Ordinates $PM$ and $QN$ are drawn to this diameter". I think you misinterpreted this: an ordinate to a diameter is a line, parallel to the tangent at the intersection between that diameter and the ellipse.

Comment: @Aretino yeah I was suspecting that I possibly haven't taken the meaning of the question right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a parabola the abscissa is proportional to the square or the related ordinate, that is:
$$
RM=kPM^2,\quad RN=kQN^2.
$$
On the other hand, by similar triangles we have:
$$
\begin{align}
VM/VN &= PM/QN \\
(VM+VN)/VN &= (PM+QN)/QN \\
(RN-RM)/VN &= (PM+QN)/QN \\
k(QN^2-PM^2)/VN &= (PM+QN)/QN \\
k(QN-PM)QN &= VN \\
kQN^2-kPM\cdot QN &= VN \\
RN-kPM\cdot QN &= VN \\
RN-VN &= kPM\cdot QN \\
RV &= kPM\cdot QN.
\end{align}
$$
Hence:
$$
RV^2 = kPM^2\cdot kQN^2 =RM\cdot RN.
$$
[image]